# Listbox contains does not find item, cannot remove an item

Tags: c#, object

I add items to a list box like so:

```
foreach(myObject object in ListOfObjects)
{
    mylistbox1.add(object);
}

foreach(myObject object in ListOfObjectsTwo)
{
    mylistbox2.add(object);
}
```

Further on, I want to remove a couple of items given a specific condition. This is what I do:

```
foreach(myObject object in ListOfObjects3)
{
    mylistbox1.items.remove(object);
    mylistbox2.items.remove(object);
}
```

This only seems to work for `mylistbox1` but not `mylistbox2`. When I debug, I can see that the item is there and that it has the exact same properties as the one I'm trying to remove. When I try to check if the listbox contains the item im trying to remove, it returns false.

I can't seem to make sense of it.

Comment: Maybe you could give us example of initialisation your `ListOfObjects`, `ListOfObjectsTwo` and `ListOfObjects3`?

Comment: @FSou1 they are objects created in another class that consist of a string and a boolean. They are initialized like " Object o = new Object(string str, bool bl);

Comment: `object` is not a valid identifier.

Comment: Does `myObject` implement its `Equals` method to compare its properties? I'll bet you're comparing _references_ to different objects, even if they have the same property values.

Comment: You should override `Equals` in `myObject`, othwerwise `Remove` tries to find the object with `ReferenceEquals`. Reference equality means that the object variables that are compared refer to the same object (not just equal).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I c# all lists operation that are in some way required to compare objects use `Equals` or `GetHashCode` methods. In your case `Equals` and the default implementation wont check properties values it will only verify if the passed as argument object is in list so consider if you have the same instance in your list or just two different instances that happened to have the same properties. (the helpful VS option is `make object id` it will mark instance with a number)

If this is the case then you should consider overriding `Equals` method or find the instance that you want to delete with `linq` for example and pas that object to `Remove` method.

Comment: I was in fact comparing two different instances. I implemented my own equals method that does what I want. Thank you!